# Interface builder is crashing upon startup

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios4, crash

I downloaded xcode 3.2 and the iphone sdk 4.1, which has been working wonderfully, until a few days ago. For some reason whenever I open interface builder by clicking on a xib file all the pictures in the buttons and imageviews display a big blue question mark, and then interface builder gives me this:

Assertion Message: An uncaught exception was raised.

Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Reason: *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: ../goldnquartz.jpg)
User Info: (null)

And asks if I want to crash or continue. If I continue, I cannot do anything useful in IB. I also made a new blank .xib file and tried to open that file with IB, but I got the same message.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today. It was a broken image file.

Comment: yes, that was it. I replaced the image file with a different one with the same name, and it worked.